# How to do the single element view should look like multi in react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

How to do in single element removal as in multi in react-select?
The single element view should look like multi. in the sense with the delete button
[image]

```html
<Select

    isMulti
    name="colors"
    options={colourOptions}
    className="basic-multi-select"
    classNamePrefix="select"
  />
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/vozjb?module=/example.js

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve, it is better if you provide some more details.

Comment: The single element view should look like multi. in the sense with the delete button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `react-select` you have `styles` prop which can be used for styling,

```
<Select
  isClearable
  defaultValue={options[0]}
  options={options}
  styles={customStyles}
/>
```

And the `styles` are,

```
const customStyles = {
  singleValue: styles => ({ ...styles, 
  color: '#f3f4f5',
  backgroundColor: '#000',
  padding: 5,
  marginRight: 10,
  borderRadius: 4,
  // ...cross()   //This will give you feel of multi select but clicking on this will not work
  }),
  clearIndicator: (base, state) => ({
  ...base,
  cursor: 'pointer',
})
}
```

For Clearing as `multi-select`, you can use `isClearable` prop.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5cuswx)

---

**Update**

Another way is, restricting `multi-select` to select only `1`. For this you need to keep a copy of options in `state` and pass options from state, and using `onChange` you can restrict,

```
<Select
  isMulti
  options={this.state.option}
  onChange={values => this.handleSelectChange(values)}
/>
```

And `handleSelectChange` function should be,

```
handleSelectChange = (value) =>{
    if(value!==null){
      if(value.length === 1){
        this.setState({option: value})
      }else{
        this.setState({option: options}) //here options is original options
      }
    }else{
      this.setState({option: options})
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to click on X to delete an item?

Comment: I would suggest you to use default delete option, i.e. why I commented that part.

Comment: Making `X` onclick delete will create an anti-pattern for single `react-select`.

Comment: or can one put in multi the maximum quantity of choice 1?

Comment: I went with the 2nd solution (multi-select restricted to 1 selection) and hid the blinking cursor next to the single selected item this way on the onChange event of the react-select component : document.getElementById("myBlock").getElementsByTagName('input')[0].style.display = "none";

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Select from "react-select";
import { colourOptions } from "./docs/data";

export default () => {
  const [x, setX] = useState({
    value: "ocean",
    label: "Ocean",
    color: "#00B8D9",
    isFixed: true
  });
  return (
    <Select
      value={x ? [x] : []}
      isMulti
      name="colors"
      options={colourOptions}
      className="basic-multi-select"
      classNamePrefix="select"
      onChange={values => setX(values ? values[values.length - 1] : undefined)}
    />
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-single-as-milti-snwm1

Comment: Loos like the correct link is https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-single-as-milti-x1k57